# Como remover parte de uma string usando um vetor?

Tags: r, string

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Suponha o seguinte dataset:

```
pilots <- 
tibble(driver_name = c("Jack Aitken",
                       "Christijan Albers","Alexander Albon *","Michele Alboreto",
                       "Jean Alesi","Jaime Alguersuari","Philippe Alliot **",
                       "Cliff Allison","Fernando Alonso ~","Giovanna Amati",
                       "George Amick","Red Amick +","Chris Amon","Bob Anderson",
                       "Conny Andersson","Emil Andres --","Mario Andretti ^",
                       "Michael Andretti"),
       nationality = c("United Kingdom","Netherlands",
                       "Thailand","Italy","France","Spain","France",
                       "United Kingdom","Spain","Italy","United States",
                       "United States","New Zealand","United Kingdom","Sweden",
                       "United States","United States","United States"))


# A tibble: 18 x 2
   driver_name        nationality   
   <chr>              <chr>         
 1 Jack Aitken        United Kingdom
 2 Christijan Albers  Netherlands   
 3 Alexander Albon *  Thailand      
 4 Michele Alboreto   Italy         
 5 Jean Alesi         France        
 6 Jaime Alguersuari  Spain         
 7 Philippe Alliot ** France        
 8 Cliff Allison      United Kingdom
 9 Fernando Alonso ~  Spain         
10 Giovanna Amati     Italy         
11 George Amick       United States 
12 Red Amick +        United States 
13 Chris Amon         New Zealand   
14 Bob Anderson       United Kingdom
15 Conny Andersson    Sweden        
16 Emil Andres --     United States 
17 Mario Andretti ^   United States 
18 Michael Andretti   United States
```

O propósito é remover os símbolos que vêm junto com os nomes de alguns pilotos.

Sei que se eu fizer um levantamento de todos os símbolos, consigo passá-los individualmente em uma função `str_remove_all()`:

```
pilots %>% 
  mutate(driver_name = str_remove_all(driver_name, "--|[\\~|\\+|\\*|\\^|\\**]"),
         driver_name = str_trim(driver_name))

# A tibble: 18 x 2
   driver_name       nationality   
   <chr>             <chr>         
 1 Jack Aitken       United Kingdom
 2 Christijan Albers Netherlands   
 3 Alexander Albon   Thailand      
 4 Michele Alboreto  Italy         
 5 Jean Alesi        France        
 6 Jaime Alguersuari Spain         
 7 Philippe Alliot   France        
 8 Cliff Allison     United Kingdom
 9 Fernando Alonso   Spain         
10 Giovanna Amati    Italy         
11 George Amick      United States 
12 Red Amick         United States 
13 Chris Amon        New Zealand   
14 Bob Anderson      United Kingdom
15 Conny Andersson   Sweden        
16 Emil Andres       United States 
17 Mario Andretti    United States 
18 Michael Andretti  United States
```

Mas, como fazer essa remoção de uma forma mais prática usando um vetor?

Para obter o vetor a partir da coluna "driver_name", fiz:

```
simbolos <- pilots %>% 
  mutate(driver_name = str_remove_all(driver_name, "[:alpha:]|\\s")) %>% 
  pull(driver_name)


> simbolos
 [1] ""   ""   "*"  ""   ""   ""   "**" ""   "~"  ""   ""   "+"  ""   ""   ""  
[16] "--" "^"  ""
```

Imaginei que poderia usar `%in%`.

```
pilots %>% 
  mutate(driver_name = str_remove_all(driver_name %in% icones))

Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `driver_name`.
i `driver_name = str_remove_all(driver_name %in% icones)`.
x argument "pattern" is missing, with no default
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

No entanto, não estou sabendo aplicar.

A função `str_remove_all()` lida com padrões, não com vetores

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma abordagem diferente: remover espaço seguido de caracteres não alfabéticos no final das *strings*. Vou usar um exemplo diferente do seu para incluir o caso de sobrenomes compostos:

```
nomes <- c("Jack Aitken", "Alexander Albon *","Michele Alesi-Alboreto",
           "Philippe Alliot **", "Fernando Alonso ~", "Red Amati-Amick +",
           "Emil Andres --","Mario Andretti ^")

sub("\\s\\W.*$", "", nomes)
#> [1] "Jack Aitken"            "Alexander Albon"        "Michele Alesi-Alboreto"
#> [4] "Philippe Alliot"        "Fernando Alonso"        "Red Amati-Amick"
#> [7] "Emil Andres"            "Mario Andretti"
```

Ou, com `stringr::str_remove`:

```
str_remove(nomes, "\\s\\W.*$")
```

Answer (score 3):

## R base

Uma solução com uma regex e R base.
A regex nega (`^`) as classes alfabética e de espaços. E substitui tudo por `""`.

```r
trimws(gsub("[^[:alpha:][:space:]]", "", pilots$driver_name))
#>  [1] "Jack Aitken"       "Christijan Albers" "Alexander Albon"  
#>  [4] "Michele Alboreto"  "Jean Alesi"        "Jaime Alguersuari"
#>  [7] "Philippe Alliot"   "Cliff Allison"     "Fernando Alonso"  
#> [10] "Giovanna Amati"    "George Amick"      "Red Amick"        
#> [13] "Chris Amon"        "Bob Anderson"      "Conny Andersson"  
#> [16] "Emil Andres"       "Mario Andretti"    "Michael Andretti"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

## `tidyverse`

Com a mesma regex, mas os espaços depois da remoção dos caracteres especiais são removidos na linha seguinte para tornar o código mais legível.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(tibble)
  library(stringr)
})

pilots <- 
  tibble(driver_name = c("Jack Aitken",
                         "Christijan Albers","Alexander Albon *","Michele Alboreto",
                         "Jean Alesi","Jaime Alguersuari","Philippe Alliot **",
                         "Cliff Allison","Fernando Alonso ~","Giovanna Amati",
                         "George Amick","Red Amick +","Chris Amon","Bob Anderson",
                         "Conny Andersson","Emil Andres --","Mario Andretti ^",
                         "Michael Andretti"),
         nationality = c("United Kingdom","Netherlands",
                         "Thailand","Italy","France","Spain","France",
                         "United Kingdom","Spain","Italy","United States",
                         "United States","New Zealand","United Kingdom","Sweden",
                         "United States","United States","United States"))



pilots %>%
  mutate(driver_name = str_remove_all(driver_name, "[^[:alpha:][:space:]]"),
         driver_name = trimws(driver_name))
#> # A tibble: 18 × 2
#>    driver_name       nationality   
#>    <chr>             <chr>         
#>  1 Jack Aitken       United Kingdom
#>  2 Christijan Albers Netherlands   
#>  3 Alexander Albon   Thailand      
#>  4 Michele Alboreto  Italy         
#>  5 Jean Alesi        France        
#>  6 Jaime Alguersuari Spain         
#>  7 Philippe Alliot   France        
#>  8 Cliff Allison     United Kingdom
#>  9 Fernando Alonso   Spain         
#> 10 Giovanna Amati    Italy         
#> 11 George Amick      United States 
#> 12 Red Amick         United States 
#> 13 Chris Amon        New Zealand   
#> 14 Bob Anderson      United Kingdom
#> 15 Conny Andersson   Sweden        
#> 16 Emil Andres       United States 
#> 17 Mario Andretti    United States 
#> 18 Michael Andretti  United States
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>